# International website setup with mulitple languages (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

My international website requires a dedicated version of wordpress for each language, following this kind of subdirectory structure:

```
example.com/en
example.com/es
example.com/fr
...
```

I have multisite installed. In addition to the wordpress installation in the current root (example.com), each language has its dedicated wordpress installation in the respective subdirectory.

Now, my question is:

How do I make example.com/en, example.com/es etc. the new root/index directory depending on the country the site is being visited from (e.g. what changes need to be made to the .htaccess file)? The current root example.com shall never be accessed, only the respective subdirectories. How do the big companies do it?

Thanks so much in advance for any help.

Comment: "The big companies" do _not_ have separate sites for each language!

Comment: Apart from that: there are various libraries offering geolocation data to map IP addresses to a geographic location. That is not precise, it does not work in all cases, but mostly, as long as no VPNs are involved, no proxies, no mapped networks, not huge company networks and and and. PHP for example offers the "GeoIP" extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Comment: Hello you can using wpml wordpress plugin through create  setup 

Plugin Url : https://wpml.org/